# Simple group order $168$ and $2$-transitive permutation subgroup of $S_7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

I am interested in the permutation representation of the simple group $ G $ of order $ 168 $ given by
$$
G=\langle (45)(67),(142)(356)\rangle
$$
I think this permutation representation is $2$-transitive. For example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSL(2,7))
says that viewing the simple group of order $168$ as $ GL_3(2)=PGL_3(2)=SL_3(2)=PSL_3(2) $ there is a natural $2$-transitive action on the $ 7 $ points of the Fano plane.

My question: **Is the subgroup $ \langle(45)(67),(142)(356)\rangle $ of $ S_7 $ $2$-transitive?**

Comment: It isn't difficult to find enough permutations that stabilize $1$ and permute the others transitively. For example $\gamma=(142)(356)(45)(67)=(1467352)$ is a 7-cycle. If you conjugate $(45)(67)$ by the powers of $\gamma$, and set aside those conjugates that share $1$ as a fixed point, you should get enough.

Comment: But basic linear algebra tells us that $SL_3(2)=GL_3(2)$ acts 2-transitively on the set of seven non-zero vectors of $\Bbb{F}_2^3$, and that should be an easier way. After all, any two such vectors are automatically linearly independent because $1$ is the only non-zero scalar.

Comment: I thought it was given (or known) that those two permutations generate the group. With a suitable numbering of the points on $\Bbb{F}_2^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ they probably become linear.

Comment: ok that's totally reasonable I'll update my question with the linear transformation these two permutations corresponds to.

Comment: You could have posted the later parts as an answer also :-)

Comment: Lol true I guess I'll just do that

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen let me know if you think of any especially nice argument that this map between $ G $ and $ GL_3(2) $ is an isomorphism because right now thats all a bit fuzzy to me. I suppose one could argue that it is homomorphism by naturality then must be injective since $ G $ is simple then must be surjective by comparing size of $ G $ and $ GL_3(2) $? But that seems to be using a lot of facts I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's number the eight vectors in $ \mathbb{F}_2^3 $ by the numbers whose binary expansion they correspond to. So for example the standard basis is
$$
 1\sim \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, 2 \sim \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, 4 \sim \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix},
$$
Then $ (45)(67) $ is the linear map
$$
\tau=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And $ (142)(356) $ is the linear map
$$
\sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
As @Jyrki Lahtonen points out it is basic linear algebra that $ GL_3(2) $ is $2$-transitive on the non zero vectors of $ \mathbb{F}_2^3 $ (since, again as he points out, any two distinct nonzero vectors over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ are linearly independent). Since $ G $ is order $ 168 $ and $ GL_3(2) $ is order $ 168 $ then then $ \langle \tau,\sigma\rangle=GL_3(2) $ (this kind of assumes that the map $ G \to GL_3(2) $ is an isomorphism, or at least injective, which is maybe obvious, but not totally obvious to me?). So $ \langle\tau,\sigma\rangle $ is $2$-transitive and thus so is $ G $.